# Throwing immediately wrapped exceptions

Tags: java, exception

Does it make sense to immediately wrap and throw exceptions to provide more context/reason as to why the exception was thrown?

For example, assuming `CustomException` is a custom exception for the particular application/module:

```
throw new CustomException(new UnsupportedOperationException("Feature X is no longer supported. :("));
```

Would it be more standard to simply pick one or the other?  For example:

```
throw new CustomException("Feature X is no longer supported. :(");
```

or

```
throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Feature X is no longer supported. :(");
```

I understand that it's fairly standard practice to throw wrapped exceptions if they're being rethrown / from a catch block but I don't think I've seen throwing wrapped exceptions from scratch (using `new`).

Comment: `throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Feature X is no longer supported. :(");` would make more sense. Why would you want to wrap it? It describes properly what went wrong.

Comment: Wrapping it provides the context that it happened within this part of the application.  Notably, at higher levels, there are existing catch blocks for `CustomException` to catch errors that originate in this particular module without crashing the whole application.  It is also possible to throw an `UnsupportedOperationException` here and catch it higher up or wrap it somewhere in between.

Comment: Then I would say there is probably an issue with those existing `catch`-all blocks :).

Comment: A `CustomException` thrown simply means that the module was unable to successfully complete it's job and an exception was encountered while doing so.  The callers of this module would know how to handle this module failing, whether it's simply logging failure, trying again, trying something different, or giving up.  Importantly, callers only care that the module did not complete the operation and the information as to "why" is mostly used for logging.  The module does not necessarily fail from all internal exceptions and handles most of the non-fatal exceptions that arise based on their cause.

Comment: The `catch`-all situation would also apply to APIs where I naturally encounter an exception (i.e. through a Java library call), `catch` that particular exception and rethrow it wrapped in `CustomException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a case where creating a wrapped exception like this is a good idea.

Filling in stack traces is relatively expensive, and creating a duplicate stack trace is a waste.

Exception chaining and suppressed exceptions are primarily for logging; applications that inspect this information in order to control flow are fragile. Any extra information you want to convey can be put in the message for logging with the stack trace.

The exception mechanism is based on the exception type, and handlers should primarily rely on that for flow control. If additional information is needed, it can be exposed through specific API on the custom exception.

In the case of a deprecated API, throwing `UnsupportedOperationException` is the best choice. It is a programming error to upgrade a library to an incompatible version. This doesn't occur unpredictably at runtime; the developer can and should discover this problem during development.

If runtime exceptions are caught, it should be at a high level in the application. For example, a Servlet engine might catch and report runtime errors without aborting the whole process, protecting other applications. A GUI might catch runtime exceptions arising from event dispatch without crashing the whole application.

In other cases, throwing a new `CustomException` might be better. A subclass of `CustomException` could be used to report a type of error that might be recoverable. For example, suppose usernames must be unique. Your application could check to see if a username is taken, and then create an account if the name is available, but this introduces a race condition where another user might claim that name in the meantime. By attempting optimistically to create the user account, and failing with a specific `DuplicateUsernameException` if the username is not available, a handler can prompt for a new username.

Answer (score 1):

> Does it make sense to immediately wrap and throw exceptions to provide more context/reason as to why the exception was thrown?

When you catch an exception and wrap it, this makes perfect sense. Adding the context information is one reason to do it. Another reason is to make it a different kind of exception altogether in order for it to be suitable for the callers of *your* API (as opposed to being suitable to your API's implementation).

Consider an example: your library uses an RDBMS backend to store some data, with referential integrity constraints turned on. One of these constraints could reject duplicate records of some kind for the same user ID. In this case your library would catch `SQLException` indicating that the referential integrity constraint is violated. However, your library should not throw `SQLException` to its users. Instead, it should throw a custom `DuplicateUserRecordException` with user ID and `SQLException` inside.

However, creating an exception with another exception nested inside (i.e. doing literally what your first example does) is not a good idea. The main reason for wrapping an exception inside another exception, as opposed to providing an unrelated exception, is to retain the place where the exception has been thrown. However, your nested exception is never thrown, so it has no useful context embedded inside it.

Comment: I agree with your analysis, but it's not applicable to this question. Here, the user is directly instantiating *both* exceptions at the same site, not catching and wrapping an exception from another layer. This is a bad idea. In this case the context is identical for both exceptions. And catchers generally should not interrogate a wrapped exception to control handling flow because it violates the abstraction layer and increases coupling.

Comment: @erickson That's an interesting observation. I assumed that OP was wrapping and throwing an exception that he has already caught, and that the example where he calls `new` on both exceptions at the same time is just for an illustration. I edited the answer to reflect your comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For your case I would say

```
throw new CustomException("Feature X is no longer supported. :(");
```

Unless you want top level component to know what you are throwing.
This can be either

```
1. DAO related 
2. Any exception would cause another exception 
3. multiple exception would occur
```

For example if this feature X if yours might throw IOException and FileNotFoundException. You dont want to return both to the upper component then you should wrap it. But you know the feature X doesn't have any impact to the caller class then you can just end it with the custom exception.